# MKMapView centerLocation

Tags: ios, mkmapview, cllocation

In my application there is an `MKMapView` and I am trying to get the center coordinates of the map region that is currently visible. I am using following method so that if user moves the visible region I'll get new center coordinates.

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView1 regionDidChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated
{

CLLocationCoordinate2D centre = [mapView centerCoordinate];

NSLog(@"MAP CENTER = %f,%f",centre.latitude,centre.longitude);
}
```

the problem is that when I switch to the `UIViewController` that contains `MKMapView` it gives `MAP CENTER = 0.000000,0.000000` for two times then gives the actual coordinates `MAP CENTER = 55.755786,37.617633`. I want the actual coordinates as soon as I switch to that `UIViewController`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is the coordinates `(55.755786,37.617633)` your current location ?

`MKMapView` takes some time  to get a lock on GPS to fetch the coordinates for your current location. Until then `centerCoordinate` might return `(0,0)`

Comment: it was due to this code `MKUserLocation *userLocation = mapView.userLocation;
    MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance (
                                                                    userLocation.location.coordinate, 500000, 500000);
    [mapView setRegion:region animated:NO];
`
if I remove this code it give the `centerCoordinate` `30.0000,-40.0000` I don't want that either.
so for the moment I've put static `centerCoordinate` to overcome this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try this this may help you.

```
self.mapView.centerCoordinate = self.mapView.userLocation.location.coordinate;
```